# TFS TeamBuild : AgentScope - Gated Checkin

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, build-automation, gated-checkin

I have a situation here; I have designed my TFS Team Build 2012 build template as below

1. Run all Activities with in Agent Scope except Gated Check-in
2. Send mail in case of both success and failure of build ( mail carries changeset details
3. since last successful build to this build ), send mail activity
   happens in finally block ( with in Agent Scope )
4. Gated Check-in ( this is usually the last step to be performed, outside Agent Scope )

Now, my problem is:

1. How can I include Changeset occurred through Gated-Checkin in my mail notification.
2. I cannot push Gated Checkin activity inside AgentScope nor pull out Send Email Activity     outside Agent Scope.

How can this be handled?

Comment: Wait, you want to include the changeset that occurs through the gated checkin in an email, but you want to send that email before the gated checkin occurs?

Comment: Yes,kind of !! 

Thats is how the workflow is designed ( we cannot put Gated Checkin in Agent Scope ),i need inputs on how to handle this , as i told email activity happens in finally block under agent scope to handle both success and failure

Comment: You can't do that because you don't know that changeset yet.  You are going to have to send the email after the check-in is performed.

Comment: Chris is right, you may be able to try and guess at a change set number by incrementing the last one but since change set numbering spans all projects in the collection you'd have to ensure nobody checked in anything across you entire TFS to be accurate